# access ajax/jquery returned data and place it to form field

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

A user enters an address on this form, then click on verify address, and i run this:

```
$('#verify').click(function () {

    var address = $('input[name=address]');
    var city    = $('input[name=city]');
    var state   = $('input[name=state]');
    var zip     = $('input[name=zip]');
    var country = $('select[name=country]');

    //organize the data for the call
    var data = 'address=' + address.val() + '&city=' + city.val() + '&state=' + state.val() + '&zip='  + zip.val() + '&country='  + country.val();

    //start the ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: "process.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {

            //alert (html);

            if (html!='error') {

                //show the pin long and lat form
                $('.form2').fadeIn('slow');

            } else alert('Error: Your location cannot be found');
        }
    });

    //cancel the submit button default behaviours
    return false;
});
```

process.php takes the data, and verifies that the address exists, then sends back the latitude and longitude as "longitude,latitude". How can I take that data and place it in a form field that shows up if the location is found (form fields in the form2 div). Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
$('.form2').fadeIn('slow');
```

with this:

```
$('.form2').fadeIn('slow').find('input[name=latlon]').val(html);
```

where *latlon* is the name of the input field where you want to insert the latitude and longitude.

Comment: what if they are 2 fields that need to be updated? one with the latitude, and one with the longitude? thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm litte confused but, if I understand correctly, you can split response by "," separator and simply put each one in respective field. Like this:

```
if (html!='error') {
    var response = html.split(',');

    $('.form2').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.form2 input.longitude').attr( 'value', response[0] );
    $('.form2 input.latitude').attr( 'value', response[1] );
} else {
    alert('Error: Your location cannot be found');
}
```

Comment: bruno, that's exactly what I want to do... but for some reason the values are not showing up on the fields. I might be doing something wrong. <input name="latitude" id="latitude" type="text" size="47">

Comment: If you want to use bruno's code then replace input.longitude with input#longitude and input.latitude with input#latitude - it also might be worth reading this -> http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: rATRIJS, thanks so much. Works! Will now read the link you sent. Thanks again.